# Why can I not access some fields of a publicIpAddress in template output?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-rest-api, azure-public-ip

In my template output, I'd like to return the allocated public IP address.
I tried the following in the "outputs" section: (in an output of 'object' type)

```
"ipobj":   "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName'),'2020-07-01','Full')]"
```

This works and returns the whole publicIpAddress object:

```
  "ipobj": {
    "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
    "location": "eastus",
    "sku": {
      "name": "Basic",
      "tier": "Regional"
    },
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "resourceGuid": "...",
      "ipAddress": "...",
      "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
      "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
      "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
      "dnsSettings": {
        "domainNameLabel": "simplelinuxvm-zktwk4fzmy5p4",
        "fqdn": "simplelinuxvm-zktwk4fzmy5p4.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
      },
      "ipTags": [],
      "ipConfiguration": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/simpleLinuxVMNetInt/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1"
      }
    },
    "subscriptionId": "...",
    "resourceGroupName": "...",
    "scope": "",
    "resourceId": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/simpleLinuxVMPublicIP",
    "referenceApiVersion": "2020-07-01",
    "condition": true,
    "isConditionTrue": true,
    "isTemplateResource": false,
    "isAction": false,
    "provisioningOperation": "Read"
  }
```

This is in line with the [API documentation of the publicIpAddress object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/publicipaddresses).
And I can retrieve **some** of the properties as well, using the reference without the *'Full'* parameter, which, according to the [Azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#reference), should return the `properties` of the object.
These work:

```
"[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
"[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).publicIPAddressVersion]"
```

But some other properties are not accessible:

```
"[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).ipAddress]"
"[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName'),'2020-07-01','Full').properties.ipAddress]"
```

According to the error message, (in case of the middle example):

```
The template output '...' is not valid: The language expression property 'ipAddress' doesn't exist, available properties are 'provisioningState, resourceGuid, publicIPAddressVersion, publicIPAllocationMethod, idleTimeoutInMinutes, dnsSettings, ipTags'
```

So it seems like Azure doesn't let me access the properties which are however there in the full output.
Is there any explanation/intention behind that, or a workaround at least ?

Note: the same happens if I define a "string" output (i.e. not as part of an object) as

```
"ip": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).ipAddress]" 
}
```

or

```
"ip": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName'),'2020-07-01','Full').properties.ipAddress]"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue recently, and below are some of the references where the reason for this scenario is mentioned.

1. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/276615/arm-template-output-why-can-i-not-access-the-ipadd.html):

   i)

   > The 'ipaddress' property only exists if the 'publicIPAllocationMethod'
   > is set to 'Static'. ( A Static Public IP Address). If you did this on
   > an IP Address that was not static, it would return an error, but work
   > for those that were static.

   ii)

   > It will only have the 'ipAddress' Property when attached to a service
   > or VM which is running. If the VM is 'Stopped', it will not have the
   > ipAddress property.
2. And, looks like there is an open issue in github in this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/4234#issue-293201312), related to this. Refer to this, in case it gets resolved in the future.
3. Check this [link](https://serverfault.com/a/869099) as well, where it is mentioned that:

   > This is a known limitation in the platform where a dynamic public IP
   > address doesn't resolve itself until the VM is up and running. There
   > are two options to workaround:
   >
   > i) Create the Public IP Address in static mode. That will ensure that
   > Public IP address is immediately allocated. However, note that you
   > might incur additional charges.
   >
   > ii) Change the dependency from Public IP address to the Virtual Machine
   > that the IP address is attached to. This will ensure that the public
   > IP address is always available.

Answer (score -1):

When you output the properties of publicIpAddress object, you should pay attention to define the correct **type** that matches the output value.

```
"outputs": {
    "publicIpipAddress": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPAddresses_vmc_backupPublicIP_name'),'2020-07-01','Full').properties.ipAddress]"
    },
    "idleTimeoutInMinutes": {
        "type": "int",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPAddresses_vmc_backupPublicIP_name'),'2020-07-01','Full').properties.idleTimeoutInMinutes]"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for idleTimeoutInMinutes but I still get the same error for ipAddress.

Comment: Hi, could you please copy the full or exact sample in my rely? You should try `"value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName'),'2020-07-01','Full').properties.ipAddress]" `instead of `"value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).ipAddress]" ` in your tried sample to output the publicIpAddress. You miss the properties and api version when you tried it.

Comment: I've tried that already.
The template output 'ip' is not valid: The language expression property 'ipAddress' doesn't exist, available properties are 'provisioningState, resourceGuid, publicIPAddressVersion, publicIPAllocationMethod, idleTimeoutInMinutes, dnsSettings, ipTags'.."

Comment: Did you try the `"value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName'),'2020-07-01','Full').properties.ipAddress]"`? Could you show any screenshots about it?

Comment: I cannot add images in comments, but I copied the error message above and copied the used output from the template into the original question.

Comment: It's weird. This always works on my side. Is it a public Ip address assigned to an Azure VM?

Comment: Yes, the public IP address is fine, and the DNS name as well. I can access the machine from the internet.
What is also strange that the error message is also in line with what properties I can access. ipAddress is not listed, and I cannot access it. So can there be some account/subscription specific setting which doesn't allow access to it ? But that would make no sense as I can access the whole structure, see above.

Comment: if you can access the whole object，you should get public ip as well. Check any typo or blank when you run it.

Comment: Once again, check the error message. Azure doesn't let me access the ipAddress field, although it should, but only a few fields within the properties. 
"The language expression property 'ipAddress' doesn't exist" - I can't see any typo here.
As shown in the original question, I can access the whole object.

Comment: Could you show the full ARM template when you validate it? What's role of the Azure account are you using for arm deployment?

Comment: Subscription / My permissions says:
You have the following access:

    You are a member of the group 'idm-... ()' which has been assigned the role 'Reader' (type BuiltInRole) and has access to <subscription>
    You are a member of the group 'idm-... ()' which has been assigned the role 'Contributor' (type BuiltInRole) and has access to <subscription>